# Bad Request on HTTP.Post with Discord Bot

Tags: api, discord, bots, bad-request

Greetings and thank you for tending to this question!

I am trying to have my Discord bot create a Scheduled Guild Event.
A Calendar event for players and attendees to join a voice channel.
I am trying to achieve that by doing a POST call to Discord's API, and I am failing with the following error.
*The following message was produced from a Postman test.*

```
{
    "code": 50109,
    "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."
}
```

As the message implies something is off with my JSON body.
Below follows a version of the JSON body I am trying to send!

```
{
  "name": "The Bot created this!!!",
  "privacy_level": 2,
  "scheduled_start_time": "2022-06-15T15:00:00+00:00",
  "description": "The Bot also described this!!",
  "channel_id": 980830611458426901,
  "entity_type": 2
}
```

I tried to follow the API's documentation as perfect as I could with no positive results!!
If you wish to follow the documentation yourselves here's the link:
[Create Guild Scheduled Event](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild-scheduled-event#create-guild-scheduled-event)

> ***I am definitely missing something or adding something that should be added to the JSON body***
> ***of a different type!!! Any insights welcome!***

**What I know and tried**

- My authentication is solid because I am able to GET all events present.
- Many variations of single quotes '' and type declarations for the data in the JSON body.

Regardless of insights, Thank you for your time!!